# Replace NA-s with mean values

Tags: r

I have a data frame with values missing. How can I replace NA-s with the mean of value from the previous and next row? In the example with (30+10)/2=20.

```
id    value
1     30
2     NA
3     10
4     20
```

Comment: What do you want to do if the first or last rows have NA values? What do you want to do if you have two (or more) consecutive NA values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
library(zoo)
na.approx(df$value)
#[1] 30 20 10 20
```

Suppose if the `data` has first or last rows as NA values or consecutive NAs (it is not clear in the post), the function would return

```
 na.approx(df1$value, na.rm=FALSE)
 #[1] NA 20 25 24 23 22 27 28 29 NA
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:4, value = c(30L, NA, 10L, 20L)), .Names = c("id", 
  "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df1 <- data.frame(id=1:10, value=c(NA, 20,25, NA, NA, 22, 27, 28, 29, NA))
```